# Potential theory as a tool in extrinsic flows

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, potential-theory, harmonic-functions, geometric-analysis

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a submanifold. For a point $x$ disjoint from $M$, we can define the electric potential $\Phi(x) = \int_M \frac{dM}{|x-m|^{n-2}}$, which is smooth and harmonic where defined. We can also extend to the compactification $S^n$ by defining $\Phi(\infty) = 0$. As $\Phi$ has no local extrema, save for $\infty$, we can apply the Morse inequalities to get $1 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^im_i = \chi(S^n - M)$, with $m_i$ denoting the number of critical points of $\Phi$ with Morse index $i$.

I am interested in how the electric potential of $M$, in particular its critical set, can be used to study topological and geometric properties of $M$, particularly when $M$ is either undergoing a geometric flow or when $M$ is stationary with respect to said flow.

So far, I've been considering the case when $M$ is a fixed knot $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Using Morse theory and stable manifold theory, [I was able to show](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.01942) $|\text{Crit} \Phi| \geq 2t(K) + 2$, where $t(K)$ is the tunnel number of $K$. There are circumstances when this inequality can be sharpened, such as when $K$ is contained within a sufficiently thin planar slab. In this case, the critical set is bounded below by $2 \cdot \text{crossings}(P(K)) + 2$, with $P(K)$ denoting the slab's planar projection of the given parametrization of $K$. This result is proven with a Poincare-Hopf argument in an upcoming preprint.

The aforementioned result can be framed as a statement describing the critical set when the knot nearly minimizes a "flatness energy" which measures how much $K$ deviates from residing entirely within a plane. I'd like to find similar results with respect to more mainstream knot energies such as the Mobius and Willmore energies, where we either use $\Phi$ to deduce properties on $M$, or vice versa. Likewise, I'm also curious about the case when $M$ is a surface undergoing mean curvature flow and what happens to $\Phi$ during singularities, as singularities change the topological type of the complement, and hence the Euler characterstic. I am having difficulties finding existing literature in this vein, but does anyone have suggestions on where I should look or what methods I should consider?